# CreateStreamedFileFromUriAsync: How can i pass a IRandomAccessStreamReference?

Tags: c#, uri, storagefile

I am trying to download a file using `StorageFile` method  `CreateStreamedFileFromUriAsync` but i am confused with `IRandomAccessStreamReference` parameter. How can I pass a IRandomAccessStreamReference? It is an interface. What sould I do?

```
public static IAsyncOperation<StorageFile> CreateStreamedFileFromUriAsync(
    string displayNameWithExtension, 
    Uri uri, 
    IRandomAccessStreamReference thumbnail
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found the answer:

```
IRandomAccessStreamReference thumbnail =
    RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri(remoteUri));
IAsyncOperation<StorageFile> file1 =
    StorageFile.CreateStreamedFileFromUriAsync("duyuru.pdf", new Uri(remoteUri), thumbnail);
```

Comment: this doesnt look very meaningful i wonder if there is a comprehensive guide for CreateStreamedFileFromUriAsync